# Contents of file as input to hashtable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, hashtable

I know to read the contents of file in Objective-C, but how to take it as the input to hashtable.
Consider the contents of text file as test.txt

```
LENOVA 
HCL 
WIPRO 
DELL
```

Now i need to read this into my Hashtable as Key value pairs

```
KEY   VAlue

  1     LENOVA
  2     HCL
  3     WIPRO
  4     DELL
```

Comment: Isn't that just an array? If you are reading it in the same order that it is keyed, there is no need to implement a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse your file into an array of strings and assign each element in this array with a key. This may help you get in the right direction.

```
NSString *wholeFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"filename.txt"];
NSArray *lines = [wholeFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[lines count]];
int counter = 1;

for (NSString *line in lines)
{
    if ([line length])
    {
        [dict setObject:line forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:"%d", counter]];

//      If you want `NSNumber` as keys, use this line instead:
//      [dict setObject:line forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:counter]];

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this isn't the most efficient method of parsing your file. It also uses the deprecated method `stringWithContentsOfFile:`.

To get the line back, use:

```
NSString *myLine = [dict objectForKey:@"1"];

// If you used `NSNumber` class for keys, use:
// NSString *myLine = [dict objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

Comment: `stringWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated in favour of `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` which gives you information about what encoding was detected when reading the file and also returns an `NSError` object when there was a failure reading the file.

Comment: hey.. this is how we check the contents of hashtable right??                     
" NSLog(@"1=%@",[dict objectForKey:@"1"]); "

Comment: @suse, not quite, in the above I have used `NSNumber` class as the key, but in your comment you are trying to use `NSString` as the key. If you want `NSString` as the key, you need to change the `setObject:forKey:` part. I have edited my answer to assist you further.

Comment: wat should i write for the value of "i", its giving me an error saying 'i' is undeclared, first use inthis function?? 
Its the key value right? but how to declare it?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, that is a typo, `i` is meant to read `counter`. My mistake. Please try again.